# Auto-completion for Python commands in console of Mathematica notebooks

Tags: notebooks, python, external-language-cell

A great feature introduced in Mathematica v11.3 is the embedded external language cell:

https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/external-system-integration/evaluate-python-in-a-notebook.html?product=language

However, the auto-completion for Python commands, unfortunately, is unavailable when pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

How to implement the auto-completion in external evaluation cells for Python (and other external languages)?

Comment: That would require that the FE had a tokenized form of the python strings, which unfortunately it doesn't and would be super hard to get in there